# Take img only from the div where the script was called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

Is it possible using a js onclick function to get the image alt without using ids or class?

I'd like to take the image from here, from the div where the call was made; because how you can see there is a general div where there are all the elementes...the image and the button.

Like if the div was a parent and all the other elements are childs and u have to find the img child only from this div, even if there are multiple similar divs on the same page.

```
<div id="ww10140700815" class="post-content">

<div class="col-md-7">
<img src="../im/wall/w10140700815.jpg" alt="w10140700815"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
<span class="meta">ID: w10140700815</span>
<a class="btn btn-default">Take Alt</a>
</div>

</div>
<div id="ww10140700815" class="post-content">

<div class="col-md-7">
<img src="../im/wall/w10140700815.jpg" alt="w10140700815"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
<span class="meta">ID: w10140700815</span>
<a class="btn btn-default">Take Alt</a>
</div>

</div>
<div id="ww10140700815" class="post-content">

<div class="col-md-7">
<img src="../im/wall/w10140700815.jpg" alt="w10140700815"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
<span class="meta">ID: w10140700815</span>
<a class="btn btn-default">Take Alt</a>
</div>

</div>
```

i ve used this, bordering the img for verification, but it selects all the images on the page because i have multiple divs, as above

```
$("div > img:nth-child(1)").css('border', '4px solid black');
```

Comment: i ve tried putting all in a list and calling only the image from the specific list but it didn t worked...and i simply don't know how to do it

Comment: See my updated answer below for the correct approach.

Comment: the problem is that i can t use "this.alt" because i m not clicking on an image, i m clicking on a button near an image. I know i can put a name to that button and take that instead of the alt, but i already have 5000 images made like that and i just wanna add a button to each of them that takes out some info about them. I don t want to reedit all of them again because it s a lot of work.

Comment: My answer shows how to do this based on what you said in your question and with the code you provided. Your example does not show any buttons. Please update your question to show the structure of the HTML that you are working with.

Comment: there is the <a> which i use isted of <button>...it has the class that defines it like a button

Comment: Please see my updated answer to address your "buttons", but just FYI, when you say "button", people will think your mean `<button>`.

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML structure will remain as you show it, you would use CSS selectors to isolate the right elements for the click event as well as to locate the corresponding `img`element.

```js
// Listen for clicks on any div with the "post-content" class
$("div.post-content").on("click", function(evt){
  // Look for images that are in a child div that has a class of "col-md-7"
  var $img = $("div[class='col-md-7'] img", this);
  console.log($img.attr("alt"));  // Get its alt value
});
```

```css
.btn { cursor:pointer; display:inline-block; background:#e0e0e0; border-radius:4px; padding:5px; }
.btn:hover { box-shadow:0 0 2px #909090; }
.btn:active { box-shadow:0 0 2px #303030; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ww10140700815" class="post-content">
  <div class="col-md-7">  
    <img src="../im/wall/w10140700815.jpg" alt="w10140700815"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <span class="meta">ID: w10140700815</span>
    <a class="btn btn-default">Take Alt</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="ww10140700815" class="post-content">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <img src="../im/wall/w10140700825.jpg" alt="w10140700825"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <span class="meta">ID: w10140700825</span>
    <a class="btn btn-default">Take Alt</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="ww10140700815" class="post-content">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <img src="../im/wall/w10140700835.jpg" alt="w10140700835"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <span class="meta">ID: w10140700835</span>
    <a class="btn btn-default">Take Alt</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could nest it in a div that gets its child, or you could add it to the img for a simpler time

```
<div id="ww10140700815" class="post-content">

<div class="col-md-7">
<img onclick="alert(this.getAttribute('alt'))" src="../im/wall/w10140700815.jpg" alt="w10140700815"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
<span class="meta">ID: w10140700815</span>
<a class="btn btn-default">Take Alt</a>
</div>
```

Best,

Dhruv